# Case When unable to determine equal values

Tags: sql-server-2008, rounding, case-when

I am trying to confirm the values my database is calculating are correct. The query that I have written gives me this information. The Pull_through column is generated by the database and the column labeled as CalcQuantity is what I am using to check the database.

```
SELECT RPT.PayPeriod
      ,RPT.Employee_Id
      ,RPT.Plan_Id
      ,RPT.Commission
      ,Pull_through
      ,Modifier
      ,ROUND(Commission * Modifier,2) AS CalcQuantity
      ,CASE WHEN Pull_through = Commission * Modifier then 'Correct'
            WHEN Pull_through <> Commission * Modifier then 'ERROR'
            END AS Confirmed
FROM Compensation..IN_Pullthrough PULL
 left join RPT
  on PULL.Employee_id = RPT.Employee_Id and PULL.Pay_Date = RPT.PayPeriod
WHERE PULL.Pay_Date = '2016-02-12'
```

The calculation is working which I have been able to confirm visually but the CASE WHEN statement is not working correctly. Originally I thought it was because I needed to round my decimal places but the Confirmed results are still showing "ERROR" for any value that does not have a zero. I've provided a screenshot of the relevant columns so you can see the query results.

[image]

Is the issue with the CASE WHEN because of the zeros or does rounding not make the results equal according to SQL?

I have to update the information every month and run a stored procedure for the database to calc new results which is why I have built this audit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us your original data.

Comment: are you comparing a float with a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit speculative, but one thing you could try is to compare the LHS and RHS of your `CASE` statement only up to the second decimal place:

```
CASE WHEN ROUND(Pull_through, 2) = ROUND(Commission * Modifier, 2)
    THEN 'Correct'
    ELSE 'ERROR'
END AS Confirmed
```

Comment: Okay that did it. Should have thought of that I guess. Thanks!